# iPhone: Handle multiple action sheets

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiactionsheet

One of my views uses 3 action sheets that come from when various buttons are clicked.  Since I only have one `- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex` method, what is the best way to know which action sheet I am dealing with? Choosing the first button on any of my actionSheets would be buttonIndex 0.  So I need to know how to know which actionSheet call that is coming from.

Ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set the tag when you create the action sheet and test against that in your action sheet method.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I simply set up a conditional based on the action sheet's title:

in

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {


if (actionSheet.title == @"present action sheet A") {

//do some stuff

}
if (actionSheet.title == @"present action sheet B") {

//do some stuff

}
```

Works like a charm, not sure if action sheets have tags, maybe im wrong though.

Comment: Yes they do. I think the tag method is much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Use class level variable for 3 actionsheet. Then you can compare the source of action in the actionSheet method.

Answer (score 0):

**Set the Tag when you create an action**

```
UIActionSheet * actionSheet = 
[[UIActionSheet alloc] 
initWithTitle:@"My title" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil  otherButtonTitles:@"Option1",@"Option2", nil];

actionSheet.tag = 1100;





-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex

{

if(actionSheet.tag == 1100)
{

    switch (buttonIndex) 
    {
        case 0: 
        {  
        }
           break;
        case 1:
        {

        }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }  
}  
}
```